# How to represent large data using Google Map API in JavaScript

Tags: openlayers, google-maps

I am trying to represent data using bins as the data was too large to display each and every point simultaneously.

[image]

The problem with this also existing if the no of bins are getting larger than 15K, map hangs while zooming in and zooming out.

So I thought of using WMS, I am new to this, I have set up GeoServer, but confused how to add layer to this and how to access that layer.

Can I add layer dynamically to GeoServer as the scenario is: User Uploads a geopoints information file and then views the data in that file.

I am creating a GeoJSON data format from the uploaded file of user. So is it possible to upload that GeoJSON data as a layer at runtime with GeoServer and then ready to view.

Is the huge data representation possible using OpenLayers?

Comment: Hi and welcome to GIS stack exchange. Please take a quick look at the site [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) - you need to rephrase this as two separate questions. You should also do a quick Google search on "Google Maps WMS GeoServer" as this has been answered elsewhere already

Comment: only .shp files can be used for datasource of layer in geoserver or any other datasource also.. if yes then can i provide geojson data in a txt file as a datasource. if no then can i convert geojson data in to shp file –

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can upload data dynamically to GeoServer, e.g. using REST API http://docs.geoserver.org/2.0.0/user/extensions/rest/index.html

Yes, you can use latest OpenLayers 2 or better Leaflet or OpenLayers 3 for displaying really BIG amounts of vector data. For OpenLayers 2, use CANVAS as renderer, *not* DOM. Leaflet or OpenLayers 3 are using canvas by default.

Consider using TopoJSON instead of GeoJSON - the amount of data to be transferred is significantly smaller.

Comment: only .shp files can be used for datasource of layer in geoserver  or any other datasource also.. 
if yes then can i provide geojson data in a txt file as a datasource.
if no then can i convert geojson data in to shp file

Answer (score 1):

Geoserver as of v2.6 supports direct upload of GeoJSON in ESPG:4236 projection... 
https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/pull/2155

If your going that route; however if this is a one time thing you might want to consider an open source node.js application called mapshaper - http://www.mapshaper.org/ you can easily host your own as a server side nodejs deployment